# What the best way to storage data in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need save data of cities such as latitude, longitude, city name, state name, street, postal code.... locally for being accessed by an android application.

- This application cannot depend of internet access.

However, I will use GPS data (latitude and longitude actual) to compare with these data saved.

I did thought in the SQLLite, but I don't know if that is the better choice.

Anybody have an idea?

Att

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `SQLIte` is a suitable choice based on your need, due you want to store different registries without touch the other to be necessary.

Comment: I'm newbie in android, I will try do something.. later I post my results with sqllite

thank @jansel

Answer (score 2):

if you are familiar with DBMS. `SQLite` is the great option for data storing.

Otherwise a optional but good approach is to create separate xml files of regarding data. and read them as per your requirements.

i personally recommand XMLs for data storage as it is fast and efficient way for handling and editing data.
Still `SQLite` would work well.

Comment: yes, i work with others dbs (oracle, postgres).. so it's not a problem =)

Comment: Then you should definitely go with "sqllite". XMl parsing with data would come handy if you don't have dynamically changing data.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Sqlite The Best Opion For U as per Your Requirment.